# How can I see a particular advertisement again in the side bar?

Tags: support, advertising, sidebar

Today in the side bar I saw an advertisement for **JetBrains DataGrip**, I wanted to click it but in the same moment I saw another post with new activity, so I navigated to the post page. After I went back to the main page, I didn’t see that advertisement any longer.

I refreshed the main page few times to see that advertisement, but no luck!

Is there any way to see the required advertisement again?

Comment: Why not just google "JetBrains DataGrip" and find their website?

Comment: Surely Google will give the result. My curiosity is to know is there any way to see that ad again in SO.

Comment: The only site I've seen that has a "view previous ads" feature is Ravelry.

Comment: I do this with HNQ so it might work with ads, but if you just use the actual "back" button in your browser I believe it should return the same ads as before.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Tip: try stuff before you advice it. This actually does not work (new ads are loaded after each load, so despite navigating back you still will see different ads).

Comment: Tip: open the link in a new tab (on OS X, you can ⌘+click the link; on Windows ctrl+click should work; otherwise middle-click with your mouse). That way you can preserve your current tab but still visit interesting links.

Comment: Great question, I was wondering the same. These are the questions for which I would like the answers to elaborate on. Why do we currently not see an ad again when we press the "back" button (as it is for the list of questions or upvotes)? has it been done on purpose or is it a technical issue? and is this something SO would like to change in the future?

Comment: A classic example of why a response should be a pure function of the URL (and headers). If the server is going to include some smart, random or mutable content, then it should redirect from a generic URL to a URL that contains an identifier for that particular state. Then you don't lose a bunch of the benefits of REST. No one ever seems to notice when they are sacrificing those, until bug reports, weird feature requests and questions like this one pop up :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to see a specific ad again.

We've discussed building a "creative gallery" in the past of all current advertisers; however, as the ads are the property of the advertiser, we don't have the right to show them in places beyond the advertising agreement. Getting approval from each advertiser is difficult as many use ad agencies that don't have the approval authority.

I guess next time you'll just have to click on the ad as you know the post will still be there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I saw the ad [again](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDku.png) Today. The ad content was partially displayed (I'm not sure it is display issue or they purposely showing like this), that was my curiosity to see the ad again.

Comment: After inspect the element I understand the display issue, the [ad image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDku.png) size is `728*90`, it is supposed to shown in between the each post (between answers or in top of the question), but unfortunately is it displaying in the side bar with the `height = "90" width = "728"` that cause the weird display. Hope there is separate image required for sidebar and the [actual image](https://s1.2mdn.net/viewad/4491284/_DataGrip_cta_728x90.png) is valid for in between the posts only.

Comment: Now I can see a proper `350*250` image for the [DataGrip](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SjdAn.png) ad in the side bar.

Comment: Thansk @Arulkumar - We're looking into why the 728x90 ad would appear in the 300x250 ad size as that shouldn't happen. If you see this again, it would be great if you could grab the entire screen in your capture. In the meantime, we'll check to ensure everything is set up correctly on our side.

Comment: Today again I see that Ad. As you requested these are entire screen's screenshot [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hkf7W.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4YVS.png)

Comment: Thanks so much...we're looking into what the issue could be.

Comment: @Arulkumar - We've identified the culprit and it has been fixed.

Comment: Wow. Really great... Glad, I helped to identify the bug.

Comment: I added a post regarding one more ad display [issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324030/2451726)

Answer (score 10):

*edit* Apologies, I misread your question and assumed it was for a *job* ad, instead of a general product advertisement. My original answer below was in response to a job ad.

For product/display ads (the ones that show up above the job ads), we use [Adzerk](http://adzerk.com/) for fulfillment. As far as I can tell, they unfortunately do not have a method in place to revisit a specific advertisement.

[Danny's answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322731/115049) has more details on why that is.

---

The job ads will simply take you to [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), where you can search for the job via its title or the company.

To answer your specific question, there's currently no way to force the display of a particular job. However, they *are* targeted, which mean you have a higher chance of seeing that particular job again, since our targeting engine decided that it was probably a good match for you.

Comment: And since the OP wants so badly to see this ad, I guess your targeting engine is doing a good job! (Well, except that he wasn't able to get it back lol)

Comment: I don't think the OP was referring to the job ads but rather the large image based ads on the side. I also saw the same DataGrip ad but I did have the chance to click on it and it took me to the Jetbrains website.

Comment: ahh yeah. those are served by Adzerk, pretty sure they don't provide a method to view a specific ad :(

Comment: How does this have so many upvotes? It doesn't answer the question, doesn't provide relevant information (since the jobs system is separate from the ads system) and is just very confusing to have as an answer here....

Comment: *the jobs system is separate from the ads system* @Kevin - The OP doesn't specify whether they were looking at a job ad or not.

Comment: @BSMP Um.. yes he does? He clearly states it's an "advertisement for JetBrains DataGrip", that ain't no job son. The answer that actually provides some relevant information is now lower than this one, which is just bloat, really.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @rossipedia

Answer (score 7):

You're not going to find some sidebar ads in the job search. Stack Overflow features a series of open source ads that users propose and vote on. Once they reach a score of +6, they will start showing up in the sidebar.

You can find a list of all the currently running open source ads here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/314722

(Your ad wasn't one of these, but these ads should in the sidebar from time to time.)

Comment: And if you're facing OP's problem you  can use this list to quickly find the ad you just saw.

Comment: Except the ad OP was referring to was not a community ad and will not show up in that list. Danny's response below is the correct one.

Comment: @rossipedia Yes, I specifically pointed that out in my last sentence. But I hope that my answer may be helpful to others that do come here after seeing a community ad.