# Few Ads in the side bar are visible partially

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sidebar

With follow-up of this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322551/how-can-i-see-a-particular-advertisement-again-in-the-side-bar#comment343793_322731), few of the Ads in the side bar are not fully visible in recent time.

The actual size of the image is [300x250](https://s1.2mdn.net/viewad/5585042/PS20161_300x250.jpg), it is capable to show in the side bar, but is it visible as [220x254.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iELi.png). There is some issue with the display. Adding the whole page's [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyEzH.png)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, found the error. The ad is the correct size, but the zone size selected in our ad server on the individual creative was the old one (220x250), rather than the new 300x250.

All fixed! Thank you so much for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Just a note: Still [220x250 size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEhVA.png) images are coming in the sidebar. Hope those ad images are need to convert as 300x250.

Comment: @Arulkumar WHEW. Got the last one just now. Thanks!